# How do I change the order in a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following hash:

```
{"match"=>0, "reach"=>1, "safe"=>2, "undecided"=>3}
```

I want to change the order like below:

```
{"reach"=>1, "match"=>0, "safe"=>2, "undecided"=>3}
```

What is the most effective solution for this?

Comment: Why do you need this hash ordered? I am asking because, in theory, a hash is a data structure that doesn't have a specific order. Although in Ruby's implementation of a hash key/value pairs are order in the order in which they were added to the hash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{"match"=>0, "reach"=>1, "safe"=>2, "undecided"=>3}
.slice("reach", "match", "safe", "undecided")
# => {"reach"=>1, "match"=>0, "safe"=>2, "undecided"=>3}
```

Comment: sawa enjoys showing off newish Ruby methods, which I applaud for its education value. [Hash#slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Hash.html#method-i-slice), which is perfect here, made its debut in v2.5. I had forgotten about it and appreciated the reminder.

Comment: This is something that ActiveSupport introduced into Rails, but it's good to see that core Ruby has adopted it as well.